# Mageto 2: get custom attribute via rest api

Tags: magento2, api, custom-attributes, magento2.3.2

I have a module "extra fee", I did get order info via rest api, but I don't see "extra fee", how can I get it? anyone help me. Thank in advance.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution

**Step1:** etc/extension_attributes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInterface">
        <attribute code="extrafee" type="integer"/>
    </extension_attributes>
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface">
        <attribute code="extra_fee" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

**Step2:** etc/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface">
    <plugin name="get_extra_fee" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\OrderGet"/>
</type>
```

**Step3:** Vendor\Module\Plugin\OrderGet.php

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class OrderGet {

    protected $_orderExtensionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderExtensionFactory $orderExtensionFactory
    ) {
        $this->_orderExtensionFactory = $orderExtensionFactory;
    }

    public function afterGet(
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $subject,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $order
    ) {
        $extensionAttributes = $order->getExtensionAttributes();
        $orderExtension = $extensionAttributes ? $extensionAttributes : $this->_orderExtensionFactory->create();

        $fee = {write the logic to get the extra fee.}
        $orderExtension->setExtraFee($fee);

        $order->setExtensionAttributes($orderExtension);

        return $order;
    }
}
```

Comment: not work for me.

Comment: Any error in log file?

Comment: in my module had file extension_attributes.xml like this https://prnt.sc/pbm3g6 please check it.

Comment: But if you want this in order api you should use extension_attributes for `Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface`

Comment: yup, but my module will not work if I change for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface".

Comment: you can add another extension_attibute tag..i have updated my ans

Comment: in OrderGet.php $fee = $orderExtension->getExtraFee('extra_fee'); right?

Comment: I think so....try with this $order->getExtraFee('extra_fee')